# JNLP: how to put/keep jars (downloaded jars/files) in two different paths /repos

Tags: java, repository, java-web-start, jnlp

JNLP: how to put jars (downloaded jars/files) in two different paths /repos

Multiple applications have its own JNLP file. And those are having application specific jars (lets say 100 jars) and some using common shared jars (example 50 jars).

When we launch app1 JNLP, it download all the jars (example: 150 jars) and keep in one repo location locally. And if we launch the app2 JNLP it again download all jars (including common shared 50 jars) and keeps in its repo location (locally: example: C:/app2/repo).

Example for app1 we are downloading all files and keeping locally in C:/app1/repo
JNLP sample code:

```
<application-desc main-class="MAIN_CLASS">      
       <argument>-retries=3</argument>
       <argument>-app.repo.url=http://REPO_URL/repositoryAppSpecific.xml</argument> 
        <argument>-app.repo.url=http://REPO_URL/repositoryCommon.xml</argument>     
        <argument>-installDir=C:\app1\repo</argument>       
</application-desc>
```

And for app2 we are downloading all files and keeping locally in C:/app2/repo.

But we have some common files (jars) for both applications. So instead of keeping all downloaded files in one place, how to keep common files in two different locations/paths (example: C:aap1/repo  for application specific jars & C:/common for common/shared files)?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a jnlp that includes all the common files, then for each of your other applications create their own jnlp that references the common jnlp. To reference the common jnlp use the "extension" tag as shown here:

```
<resources>
  <j2se href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se" version="1.4+"/>
  <jar href="app1.jar" main="true"/>
  <extension name="common" href="common.jnlp" />
</resources>
```